# li:nth-child(odd) doesn't work after adding a

Tags: jquery, css

I did have a list of items which would get alternate color with the help of jQuery:

```
$('ul.follows li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alternate');
```

It was working fine till I add an `a` tag before the list items. So... now I have:

```
    <ul class="follows">
            <a href="#">
            <li class="me">
                <img src="#">
                <h3>#</h3>
                <p>#</p>
            </li>
            </a>
...</ul>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work anymore?

I could get the `<a>` inside the `<li>` but then I am not sure how the whole item would be clickable...

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't wrap an <`li>` in an `<a>`.

Comment: the `<a>` tag should inside `<li>`, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Fix your list markup (the only valid child of UL is LI), then do this:

```
ul.follows li {padding: 0;}
ul.follows li a {display: block; height: 100%;}
```

Your jQuery should work now and your LIs will be clickable over their entire width.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5ctc3/

Comment: I've done that, but for some reason the whole LIs are not clickable. Only the elements inside it are. The jQuery works now, though.

Comment: Here's a demo I did for another situation, but you can see that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9Vgsq/ I did add the height value to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your selector because of adding a new tag. You may have to do something like this

```
$('ul.follows a li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alternate');
```

This way your jquery can traverse through your html tags. I hope that helps!

-Frank

Comment: Browsers do not render the OP's HTML as it is, the query will return an empty set.